# Eigenspaces of vector-valued transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, linear-transformations

In quantum mechanics, it is natural to consider linear maps of the type $\phi: V\to L\otimes V$ ($V$ might be a Hilbert space or something less pleasant like the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space)). I will say that $v\in V$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda\in L$ (!) if $\phi v =\lambda\otimes v$.

These “eigenvalues” are not studied in classical linear algebra. They are also less natural mathematically when expressed in this manner because it is natural to view an transformation as specifying a discrete dynamical system, but I can think of no dynamical system corresponding to $\phi$. What is then the appropriate formalism here?

An important but somewhat implicit assumption in the physical context is that the “components” of the “vector-valued transformation” $\phi$ commute. More specifically, let $(e_i)$ be a basis of $L$ and define a system of transformations $(\phi^i : V\to V)$ by
$$
  \phi v = e_i\otimes\phi^i v
$$
(summation over $i$ implied). Then it is sufficient for the formalism that I am looking for to only work when the $(\phi^i)$ commute.

The only possible answer that I can think of is that the “eigenvalues” I seek are points in the spectrum of the (commutative) operator algebra generated by the $(\phi^i)$. This is certainly sufficient, but I hope there is something more specific. For example, when $V$ is infinite-dimensional but $U$ is finite-dimensional, the algebra one would need to consider could become infinite-dimensional, which seems excessive and unfortunate.